# Как избавится от большой конструкции switch case работая со списком?

Tags: java, список, switch, jframe

У меня сейчас в зависимости от выбранного элемента в `JComboBox` выполняется следующий код:

```
try {
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Saved.ser"));                          
      String currentLine;

      while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        winOne = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[0]); 
        drawOne = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[1]); 
        lossOne = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[2]);                                                      
      }

      bufferedReader.close();                           

  } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}                                                         

     winOne++;
     drawOne++;
     lossOne++;

try {
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Saved.ser");
    fileWriter.write(winOne + " " + drawOne + " " + lossOne);
    fileWriter.close();
     } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

System.out.println("Теперь в файле: " + winOne + " " + drawOne + " " + lossOne + "\n");
```

Где я вынимаю данные из файла, присваиваю их трем переменным, меняю и снова записываю в этот файл. И все это находится сейчас в:

```
switch(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0: здесь
        break;  
}
```

Список длинный и делать 100 кейсов не думаю, что правильно. Как по-другому можно сделать? Отличие кода в кейсах в том, что сохранять и соответственно вынимать он будет из разных файлов.

Comment: case "1": callFunction(string inputFile, string outputFile) break;

Comment: я не очень понял это куда и что это делает? Поместил после case 1: , но ругается на inputFile и outputFile

Comment: читаю) проблему решил иначе, без switch case вообще. Ниже опубликовал ответ.

Comment: [7 Способов рефакторинга выражения switch в Java](https://www.developer.com/design/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом (мало ли кому нужно будет). Заменил лишь несколько строк:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Saved" + comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + ".ser"));
```

и

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Saved" + comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + ".ser");
```

Поясняю. В зависимости от индекса выбранного элемента в списке - создается и читается файл `Saved(индекс).ser`. И никаких `switch case`.

Если кому-то не хочется название типа "`Saved0`", "`Saved1`", в принципе, может брать имя элемента, то есть если выбрано "`Tomato`" или "Помидор" из списка, то и название файла будет `Tomato` или "Помидор", для этого:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(comboBox.getSelectedItem() + ".ser"));
```

и

```
 FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(comboBox.getSelectedItem() + ".ser");
```